# Laravel Middleware & Service Provider flow

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel 5.4 app where I set the Locale of the app in a middleware, depending on the root domain, because I have a domain for each language. This is because of SEO & Adwords stuff, I can't change that.

Secondly I have a ViewComposerServiceProvider where I prepare Data for the Layout View. This data depends on the Language, but the language hasn't been set yet, because the ServiceProvider is executed first.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the way, that I made a GlobalVarServiceProvider that gets the language and provides it in the request

```
$lang = Cache::rememberForever("aGreatKey", function () use ($stripped_domain) {
                return Lang::where('domain', $stripped_domain)->first();
            });
$request->attributes->add(['language' => $lang]);
```

Then I can get it in the ViewComposerServiceProvider (and everywhere else)

```
$this->sprache = $request->attributes->get('sprache');
```

Important is, that the GlobalVarServiceProvider is called before the ViewComposerServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If the current workflow is invalid, you should change it.

Probably you should move choosing language into provider (same or other) to have language already set in ViewComposerServiceProvider